# How to update background fragment while changing SharedPreferences in foreground PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I recently develop a game, which contains a fragment named GameOver to show the user name and the final. The GameOver fragment has a button to let user change their name. By click that button, user will be directed to a PreferenceFragment named SettingsFragment to change his/her name. The relative preference is EditTextPreference.

Following is the code of the Button to popup the PreferenceFragment:

```
Button changeName = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.change_name);
    changeName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.play_game_container, settingsFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

The PreferenceFragment also has a button to let user return to the previous fragment, the code is:

```
Button button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.move_to_previous);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    });
```

There is a TextView in the GameOver fragment. The username is shown in the TextView. The code is pretty straight forward and probably it is not necessary to post it.

What I want is to make the TextView update after changing of username in the SettingsFragment and return to the GameOver fragment. Can someone show me how to exactly make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for a few hours, it is solved finally. The solution is really simple, just use a OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, here is the code:

```
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            score_board.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("name", "Anonymous")
                    + "\r\n" + "Your Score: " + Integer.toString(score));
        }
    };

    mSharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```